# How to use d3.time.scale to create label for each hour of day and each day of week

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

Ok there may be so many duplicates to this question on SO, I have checked almost all of them but I couldn't figure out an answer to my quest.

I have this service which gives a count of hits to my site every minute and I want to display it in a dashboard using a d3 nvd3 line graph.

I got it all working except one thing, I want the labels on the x axis to go from midnight to midnight, i.e `(00:00 to 23:00)` in intervals of 1 hour `[00:00, 01:00, 02:00, 03:00, 04:00, ..., 22:00, 23:00]`

But I am not able to get this right. I have tried all possible combinations using `d3.time.scale` but I am not getting it right. I get all random labels on x axis.

[image: screenshot]

This is the function I am currently using which gives those random values:

```
$scope.xAxisTickFormatFunction = function() {
    return function(d) {
        return d3.time.format("%H:%M")(new Date(d));
    };
};
```

After I get this timeline of a day working, I would like to do this per each day of the week too.

I really can't figure out how `d3.time.scale` works, I have been working on this since yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

The real trick is to be able to take advantage of all the built-in time formatting/interval tools in D3. Here's a very simple example, based off [this block](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3306147), where you define your time scale across the entirety of one day (24 hours) using [`d3.time.scale().nice()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#nice):

```
// Set up the SVG
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

// Define your time scale
var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([new Date, new Date])
    .nice(d3.time.day)
    .range([0, width - 50]);

// Add your axis
svg.append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(5,0)")
   .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).ticks(24).tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M")));
```

The above code produces this axis:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this but not to show the last 00:00 on the far right ?

Comment: Hi mdml, your example is not using NVD3, can I use `d3.time.scale` with NVD3?  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56808799/287948)