# nvd3 and angular - Unable to fix axis values

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I'm trying to develop a multi-chart using `angular-nvd3`.

The chart works fine, I can get data and display the values I need. The problem I've got now, is that I'd like to display on the `x-axis` some specific values, but I can't for some reason.

here's what I've got so far: http://codepen.io/NickHG/pen/rLWNea?editors=1010

The chart options are the following:

```
chart: {
   type: 'multiChart',
   height: 450,
   margin: {
      top: 10,
      right: 40,
      bottom: 60,
      left: 30
      },
   useInteractiveGuideline: false,
   transitionDuration: 10,
   style: 'expand',
   tooltip: {
       keyFormatter: function(d, i) {
       return "Test";
       }
     },
   zoom: {
      enabled: true
     },
   xScale: x_scale,
   xAxis: {
     ticks: 14,
     domain: [0, 14],
     axisLabel: '',
     tickFormat: function(d) {
        return d3.time.format('%H:%M')(new Date(d * 1000));
      }
     },
    Axis1: {
        axisLabel: '',
        axisLabelDistance: -100
     }
 }
```

What i'm trying to achieve, is an X axis with each hour from `00:00 to 23:00` (I've also tried this but with no luck: [how to use d3.time.scale to create label for each hour of day and each day of week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926876/how-to-use-d3-time-scale-to-create-label-for-each-hour-of-day-and-each-day-of-we) )

The idea for the x axis is that I should be able to display hours, days or weeks, but I guess that once I properly understand how to display hours, I should probably be able to figure out myself how to print values in a different format.

Thanks for any help

Comment: in your pen all you need to do is change to 24 ticks... `chart.xAxis
               .scale(xAxisScale())
               .ticks(24)
               .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M"));`. see [edited pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QEggBa?editors=1010).

Comment: If you wanna put this as an answer I can select it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost all the way there. All you need to amend in your pen is the number of ticks on the x-axis from 6 to 24....

```
nv.addGraph(function() {         
      chart = nv.models.multiChart()    
      chart.margin({"left":5,"right":5,"top":10,"bottom":20})
      chart.showLegend = true
      chart.xAxis
           .scale(xAxisScale())
           .ticks(24)   //--> changed from .ticks(6)
           .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M"));
```

See [Updated pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QEggBa?editors=1010). Cheers!